# Unable to login to Magento2 admin area

Tags: magento2, admin, error, admin-panel

Using Magento 2.4.1, we are unable to login to our admin area. Error message is as below:

> UI config provider for "" is not configured.

Any ideas how to resolve please?

Error as below screenshot:

[image: UI config error]

Comment: Maybe disable custom modules first. Its not full error message.

Comment: Thanks. We don't have any custom modules on this site yet though, just blank Magento2 install with Luma theme so far. No sample data yet either.

Comment: disable ReCaptcha module if you don't use it

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this was related to ReCaptcha...... Which we don't want to use anyway.

The below command to disable ReCaptcha fixed the issue for us:

> bin/magento security:recaptcha:disable-for-user-login